# How do I use the Android Async HTTP library with Loaders?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-fragments

In my Android App, I have a number of Activities/Fragments, whose content is loaded using `Loaders` containing HTTP requests. Today, I stumbled over [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), which seems to be suited very well for HTTP requests. Now, the library takes care of running its stuff in its own Threads, so using `AsyncTaskLoader` together with the library seems not correct.

I cannot find any clues on how to integrate the Android Async HTTP library with `Loaders`, or, if I should drop the `Loaders` completely in favor of the library. If so, how would I make sure everything works fine upon configuration changes, which the `Loaders` are very good at?

I would be glad, if you could point out some blog entries on how to proberly use the library with Fragments containing Views.

Comment: i was having same problem until i made my own `http` class request without `android-async` and you can execute more than 1 `http request` at the same time , is that what you are looking for ? if so ill share my class with u

Comment: I actually was trying to avoid writing my own fail safe http request code with retries and so on. Thanks anyways, but if the lib is not working out for me I'll stay with the loader.